# Implement custom behaviour to a repository method in spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement custom behaviour to a method in Repository using `spring-data-jpa`.

The `ProductRepository` interfaces is

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository,
        ProductRepositoryCustom {

    public List findByProductName(String productName);

}
```

The `ProductRepositoryCustom` interface contain a `saveCustom` to which I want to implement custom behaviour.

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepositoryCustom {
    public Product saveCustom(Product product);
}
```

This is the implementation for `ProductRepositoryCustom` interface.
The method `saveCustom` here is just an example. What I really want to do is define a custom method such that it contains a series of instructions involving core `JpaRepository` methods. For that I tried to inject `ProductRepository` instances but I got errors as shown below.

```
public class ProductRepositoryCustomImpl implements ProductRepositoryCustom {
    @Inject
    private ProductRepository repo;

    @Override
    public Product saveCustom(Product product) {
                // other executions of methods in ProductRepository(repo)
        return repo.save(product);
    }

}
```

This is simple `ServerApp` application that I run.

```
public class ServerApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                AppContext.class);
        ProductRepository repo = context.getBean(ProductRepository.class);
        Product testProduct = new Product();
        testProduct.setProductName("Test Product");
        repo.saveCustom(testProduct);
    }
}
```

This is the stacktrace of program when I start the `ServerApp`.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepositoryCustomImpl': Bean with name 'productRepositoryCustomImpl' has been injected into other beans [productRepository] in its raw version as part of a circular reference, but has eventually been wrapped. This means that said other beans do not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)
    at devopsdistilled.operp.server.ServerApp.main(ServerApp.java:16)
```

**What can I do to implement custom behaviour like `saveCustom` ?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two problems with your classes:

remove @Repository annotation from this declaration:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepositoryCustom {
```

This will solve your current issue but [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945490/no-property-found-for-type-error-when-try-to-create-custom-repository-with-sprin) will appear.

The solution to this is to rename

```
ProductRepositoryCustomImpl
```

to

```
ProductRepositoryImpl
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm feeling stupid I didn't try removing that `@Repository` annotation, LOL. And about that second problem, I have faced that problem prior than that first one and solved it after about an hour of frustration doing some customization to my `ApplicationContext` config by using `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "packages.repo", repositoryImplementationPostfix = "CustomImpl")`

Comment: didn't know about the repositoryImplementationPostfix option, +1

Comment: You can do as `<repositories base-package="packages.repo" repository-impl-postfix="CustomImpl" />` if you're using XML based configuration. Refer to this [Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) for further detail.

Comment: @TheKojuEffect what if we do not use xml configuration? how we can put this config by code or annotation?

Comment: @Kenji Check out this doc, it's even better: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations