# Why is Spring Data's MongoRepository so limited?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

So I notice that Spring Data's MongoTemplate has a lot of different types of "save object" operations, like save, upsert, insert, and updateFirst.

Spring Data's MongoRepository interface, on the other hand, has one persistence method: "save". Now, obviously, if I want create / update / upsert functionalities, I can implement them pretty easily. Just do a get before you call "save" and check if the entity exists or not. But it seems strange that MongoTemplate has such a diversity of options (I can't even figure out what the difference between a save and an upsert is), but Spring Data's repos are so limited.

Do you think it's wasteful / lazy to use Spring Data MongoRepositories without customizing its methods if you're going to be using create / update semantics, or is the difference between a get + null check + repository.save vs. a mongoTemplate.insert too irrelevant to care about?

Answer (score 6):

You can customize your own repository using XXXRepositoryCustom and writing an implementation for it.

Here is an example:

```
public interface AccountRepository extends MongoRepository<Account, String>, AccountRepositoryCustom{

    @Query("{ 'email' : ?0 }")
    Account findByEmail(String email);

}
```

Notice the above interface extends your own AccountRepositoryCustom interface.

Then define your own AccountRepositoryCustom:

```
public interface AccountRepositoryCustom {

    public boolean updateAccountToken(String id, String token);

}
```

Next, write a implementation for it:

```
public class AccountRepositoryCustomImpl implements AccountRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public boolean updateAccountToken(String id, String token) {    
            // your code 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have done that before. But that's a lot of boilerplate code to write for the sake of getting an update and a create method when the main point of Spring Data's repositories is to reduce boilerplate code IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data follows [repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). `Repository` is an abstraction over DAO layer and serves for generic storing and retrieving domain entities. On the bottom of repository layer there is DAO layer part where is `MongoTemplate` used.

So `Repository` has logical save method. From domain point of view you shouldn't care about how is domain entity persisted at all. You just call save method and useage of `MongoTemplate` depends on `MongoRepository` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Han Wang's answer is correct, but the Impl should be named AccountRepositoryImpl   and NOT AccountRepositoryCustomImpl

see this previous question/answer :  [No property found for type error when try to create custom repository with Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945490/no-property-found-for-type-error-when-try-to-create-custom-repository-with-sprin)