# Spring Data MongoDB No property get found for type at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-java, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Data MongodB 1.4.2.Release version. For Spring Data MongoDB, I have created the custom repository interface and implementation in one location and create custom query function `getUsersName(Users users)`.

However I am still getting below exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException:
  No property get found for type Users! at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.     (PropertyPath.java:75) at
    org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327) at 
    org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:359) at
    org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:359) at
    org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307) at
    org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270) at
    org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241) at
    org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.(Part.java:76) at
    org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.(PartTree.java:201) at
    org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:291) at 
    org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.(PartTree.java:271) at 
    org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.(PartTree.java:80) at 
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:47)
```

Below is my Spring Data MongoDB structure:

```
      /*  Users Domain Object */

        @Document(collection = "users")
        public class Users {

        @Id
        private ObjectId id;

        @Field ("last_name")
        private String last_name;

        @Field ("first_name")
        private String first_name;

       public String getLast_name() {
          return last_name;
      }

      public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
     }

      public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
     }

     public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
     }
}

       /* UsersRepository.java main interface */

        @Repository
        public interface UsersRepository extends MongoRepository<Users,String>, UsersRepositoryCustom { 

             List findUsersById(String id);

         }

       /* UsersRepositoryCustom.java custom interface */

        @Repository
        public interface UsersRepositoryCustom {

           List<Users> getUsersName(Users users);
        }

       /* UsersRepositoryImpl.java custom interface implementation */

        @Component
        public class UsersRepositoryImpl implements UsersRepositoryCustom {

        @Autowired
        MongoOperations mongoOperations;


        @Override
        public List<Users> getUsersName(Users users) {
            return mongoOperations.find(
                    Query.query(Criteria.where("first_name").is(users.getFirst_name()).and("last_name").is(users.getLast_name())), Users.class);
        }

       /* Mongo Test function inside Spring JUnit Test class calling custom function with main UsersRepository interface */

        @Autowired
        private UsersRepository usersRepository;

        @Test
        public void getUsersName() {

            Users users = new Users();
            users.setFirst_name("James");`enter code here`
            users.setLast_name("Oliver");
            List<Users> usersDetails = usersRepository.getUsersName(users);
            System.out.println("users List" + usersDetails.size());


            Assert.assertTrue(usersDetails.size() > 0);
        }
```

Comment: The Custom repository does not work as mentioned in the docs - http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: It works. Looks like the implementation class name was not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The query method declaration in your repository interface is invalid. As clearly stated in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.query-methods.query-creation), query methods need to start with `get…By`, `read_By`, `find…By` or `query…by`.

Comment: Thanks Oliver for the link. Do we have to follow the query method declaration for custom methods too. I thought you can declare custom methods to start with searchBy... Or as in my above example. What should be the custom query method declaration in above case for example if I have a field name with underscore such as first_name and setter/getter methods in the domain class as getFirstName / setFirstName(String firstName)

Comment: What should be the custom query method declaration if I have a field name with underscore for example first_name both in mongodb and in my mapping domain class

Comment: You can escape underscores by adding yet another underscore, yo you'd end up with `findByFirst__name(…)`. As those method calls leak into clients, we recommend to rather stick to the Java naming conventions and not use underscores in the first place. Nonetheless, I've filed [DATACMNS-505](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-505) to include a note about the escaping mechanism into the reference documentation.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I would follow Java naming convention as per your recommendation. Great to add escaping mechanism into reference documentation.

Answer (score 0):

With custom repositories, there shouldn't be a need for method naming conventions as Oliver stated.  I have mine working with a method named updateMessageCount

Having said that, I can't see the problem with the code provided here.

I resolved this issue with the help of this post here, where I wasn't naming my Impl class correctly :

[No property found for type error when try to create custom repository with Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945490/no-property-found-for-type-error-when-try-to-create-custom-repository-with-sprin)