# Custom queries using MongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-repositories

I need to make some aggregation using `MongoTemplate`.
I am using Spring Data MongoDB, so most of my CRUD operations are made through `MongoRepository` interface. I have read about `@NoRepositoryBean` but I don't know how to use it in my case.

```
// UserRepository.java
// imports omitted
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    User findOneByUsername(String username);

    @Query(value = "{ '_id' : ?0 }", fields = "{ 'username' : 1 }")
    User getUserDetails(String userId);

}
```

---

```
// CustomUserRepo.java
// imports omitted
@Component
public class CustomUserRepo {

    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<Todo> getUserTodos(String userId){
        TypedAggregation<User> aggregation = newAggregation(
                User.class, Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("_id").is(userId)),
                Aggregation.unwind("todos")
        );
        AggregationResults<Todo> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, User.class, Todo.class);
        return groupResults.getMappedResults();
    }

}
```

How to make it as the same `UserRepository` bean?

If I inherit `UserRepository` I have to implement all methods.
If I make `CustomUserRepo` abstract it can't be instantiated.

---

**Update:**

Useful articles:

- [What's the difference between Spring Data's MongoTemplate and MongoRepository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008947/whats-the-difference-between-spring-datas-mongotemplate-and-mongorepository?rq=1)
- [No property found for type error when try to create custom repository with Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945490/no-property-found-for-type-error-when-try-to-create-custom-repository-with-sprin/13947263#13947263)

But the solution is in using conventions of class names. Is there any way to make it by class design?

Comment: I don't think you can make aggregate queries through `UserRepository` out of box. You can autowire mongo template into user repository if you wanted to keep everything in one place.

Comment: @SagarReddy you are right. I can't. The question is how to `@Autowire` it into implementation of `UserRepository`? (If I will declare necessary methods there